# Rtklib: use rtklib in an android which supports raw measurements to get accurate positions

Tags: gps, android-gps, real-time-kinematic

I am working on a project where I obtain raw gps measurements in a supported Android phone and use rtklib's Android port that is rtk-gps to correct this data with correction from a dgps base station.
So my question is - is this achievable using rtklib? Also I see that rtklib gui expect rinex format so do I need to convert the raw data i get from mobile to rinex format and feed to rtklib library?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with Android 10 or later where GNSS duty cycle can be disabled - http://www.pilablu.de/apps/gps/precise-gps-en